# Logcat's top bar is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

Logcat's top bar is missing in one of my projects.

[image: Logcat's top bar is missing]

This is the bar I am talking about.
[image: This fields are missing: mobile phone connected, option "no debuggable processes", option "Verbose", "Debug","Info", "Warn", "Error" or "Assert", text filter, regex box and "show only selected application"]

I have already tried to restart Android Studio, and restart logging but nothing happens.

This happened after I run this commands:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect <DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS>:5555
```

How can I show this bar again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clicked in Event Log twice and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug restarting Android Studio will solve.